# RedirectToAction Hanging Intermittantly in Production Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have just deployed some code to a production environment (on AWS) and intermittantly see hanging which ultimatley results in an error (the page can't be reached, or no response along those lines).

Using the inspector/developer tools in Chrome we can see the browser never receives the 302/response from the page which is meant to be redirecting them.

The redirect is pretty straightforward- something like;

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(UsersController.Login), nameof(UsersController).Replace("Controller", ""), userLogin);
```

The previous line of code writes an entry to a log so we can see the code is definitely getting this far.

Clearly the oddest issue is it only happens in the production environment and only happens intermittantly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what it could be... can you wrap the redirect in a try catch to see if there is an error? There should be an error of some kind.

Comment: @DavidC799- it is already wrapped in a try/catch which would write to a log file and redirect to an error page (neither of which are happening).